# What does this command do? setenv BIN `uname -s``uname -r | cut -d. -f1`

Tags: libraries

I'm trying to install I/O API to use CMAQ. I'm following [these instructions](https://www.cmascenter.org/download/software/ioapi/ioapi_3-2.cfm?DB=TRUE). First I downloaded the gzipped file ioapi-3.2.tar.gz,  and untarred it. But then I get stuck at the 4th step, which reads:

> 4. For each desired configuration, `setenv BIN <machinetype>`, where `<machinetype>` matches the extension on one of the `ioapi/Makeinclude.*`. Then do a top-level make dirs to build the object-directories. The usual pattern for generating BIN iS
>
>    ```
>    setenv BIN `uname -s``uname -r | cut -d. -fI`
>    ```
>
>    and then modify the result by appending any compiler specifics, e.g., for F90 or debug compiled configurations.
>
>    Linux versions 2 and 3 are binary-compatible, so `Linux2` is used for
>    both of these (and similarly for recent versions of `SunOS`). Note, for
>    example, that for `Linux2_×86*`, there are distinct (and incompatible)
>    variants for the GNU *g77/gcc*, Intel *if/icc*, Lahey-Fujitsu *If95*/GNU
>    *gcc*, and Portland Group *pgf90*/*pgcc*; **moreover, the latter is not
>    compatible with Portland Group pf90/GNU cc (when the latter is used to
>    build libnetcdf.a, as in the vendor supplied libraries on RedHat** (*that
>    incompatibility being the largest single generator of
>    installation-questions in recent years!*).

I'm really new to linux, and even more to building programs, and have no idea what this instruction means. I'm guessing I have to use "setenv BIN" for every version of I/O API I want to installed contained in the folder. I do not gget however if I should first use `setenv BIN <machinetype>` and then

```
setenv BIN `uname -s``uname -r | cut -d. -f1`
```

or if I'm just supposed to use one of the two. If so, I don't know which one of the two. It doesn't help that I don't really know what these commands are meant to do. Since I'm pretty lost here any information which clarifies any part of my problem helps. If it's relevant, I'll use GCC to build CMAQ. Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the elements of the solution you've tried in the post itself rather than relying on a link to the guide you followed. We need to understand what steps you took specifically and the error messages you got in the process as they will help us better diagnose your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepend `echo`  to see the expanded command:

```
echo setenv BIN `uname -s``uname -r | cut -d. -f1`
```

See what the embedded commands do on your system:

```
uname -s
uname -r
uname -r | cut -d. -f1
```

Do they make sense?

BUT, be aware that `setenv` is a C-shell (`csh`) builtin. Ubuntu defaults to using the Bash shell, where the equivalent command is:

```
export BIN="`uname -s``uname -r | cut -d. -f1`"
```

Beware other bash vs C-shell differences, search online. Read `man bash csh`.

In either `bash` or `csh`, an environment variable (e.g
`BIN`) can hold only the last value stored in it, so consult the documentation and the INSTALL file. You're probably going astray.